# Upload of crashlytics mapping files fails

Tags: android, gradle, proxy, crashlytics

My project setup changed a bit because of a new company VPN. Crashlytics is not able to upload the mapping.txt anymore which leads to failing release builds.

The error message is

```
Operation timed out. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.

Execution failed for task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileRelease'. 
com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.reloc.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to webproxy.some.domain:8080 failed: 
Operation timed out
```

I defined proxy settings in gradle.properties (just changed the values here)

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=webproxy.some.domain
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyHost=webproxy.some.domain
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*some.domain|localhost
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*some.domain|localhost
```